# Error in implementing windows function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

| customer_ID | date | expense_transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:100331 | 4/30/2012 | 177.43 |
| BS:100331 | 5/31/2012 | 96.9 |
| BS:100331 | 6/30/2012 | 81.31 |
| BS:100331 | 7/31/2012 | 98.13 |
| BS:100331 | 8/31/2012 | 99.95 |
| BS:100699 | 4/30/2012 | 403.99 |
| BS:100699 | 5/31/2012 | 0 |
| BS:100699 | 6/30/2012 | 3.24 |
| BS:100699 | 7/31/2012 | 11.02 |
| BS:100699 | 8/31/2012 | 11.27 |

My expected output is as shown in column `expense_transactions_3_month_max`. To arrive at this column, we first shift `expense_transactions` by one row as shown in `expense_transactions_shifted` and then calculate the max value for 3 rows. Where 3 is the windows size.

| customer_ID | date | expense_transactions | expense_transactions_shifted | expense_transactions_3_month_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BS:100331 | 4/30/2012 | 177.43 |  |  |
| BS:100331 | 5/31/2012 | 96.9 | 177.43 |  |
| BS:100331 | 6/30/2012 | 81.31 | 96.9 |  |
| BS:100331 | 7/31/2012 | 98.13 | 81.31 | 177.43 |
| BS:100331 | 8/31/2012 | 99.95 | 98.13 | 98.13 |
| BS:100699 | 4/30/2012 | 403.99 |  |  |
| BS:100699 | 5/31/2012 | 0 | 403.99 |  |
| BS:100699 | 6/30/2012 | 3.24 | 0 |  |
| BS:100699 | 7/31/2012 | 11.02 | 3.24 | 403.99 |
| BS:100699 | 8/31/2012 | 11.27 | 11.02 | 11.02 |

I have tried using this SQL query but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
 WITH shifted AS
 (
     SELECT  
         customer_ID, date,
         LAG(expense_transactions, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_ID ORDER BY customer_ID ASC) AS shiftedBy1Month 
     FROM
         FundsFlowAfterMerge ffam
)
SELECT
    customer_ID, date, 
    MAX(shiftedBy1Month) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_ID, date ORDER BY customer_ID ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rolling3Window 
FROM 
    shifted
```

Is my approach correct? I am getting below error for the above query:

> SQL Error [2809] [S0001]: The request for procedure 'FundsFlowAfterMerge' failed because 'FundsFlowAfterMerge' is a table object

Comment: After adding the missing `FROM`, I can't replicate your issue: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1cd70b3428e0fd1df982dbda457c78a6). The only way I can is by calling your table like it were a procedure (which your SQL is not doing): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f302d4d81c7f60e06893a3054158756)

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the from statement. I have added it. As you can see the output is not as expected. The value calculated is the maximum value of 3 rows. the three rows above.

Comment: @Larnu: Should I think of a different approach all together,as a combination of lag and shift function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your current query is partitioning and ordering by the wrong columns.**

- Your `lag` says `partition by customer_ID order by customer_ID  ASC` which means that it will get an arbitrary result for each `customer_ID`.
- Your `max` says `PARTITION  BY customer_ID,date order by  customer_ID ASC rows between 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT row` which means that each individual date is another partition.
- Furthermore, you seem to only want a result when you actually have 3 rows, you should take that into account
- You can write this a bit shorter. `ROWS 2 PRECEDING` is short for `rows between 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW`, also `lag` defaults to the previous row, and `ASC` is the default ordering.

```sql
with shifted as (
 
    SELECT
        customer_ID,
        date,
        lag(expense_transactions) over
          (partition by customer_ID order by date) as shiftedBy1Month
    from FundsFlowAfterMerge ffam
)
 
select
    customer_ID,
    date,
    CASE WHEN LAG(shiftedBy1Month, 2) OVER
            (PARTITION BY customer_ID order by date) IS NOT NULL
        THEN max(shiftedBy1Month) over
          (PARTITION BY customer_ID order by date ROWS 2 PRECEDING)
    END as Rolling3Window
FROM shifted
```

Comment: The logic written in case statement is: LAG(shiftedBy1Month, 2) -> lag the column shiftedBy1Monthn by 2 and check if the column value is not null. If not null then calculate the maximum value of the preceding 2 rows including the current row?

is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, in other words the already shifted row has to have a 3 values in it for it to get the `max` value. If that is not what you want you could remove the `case`, and just leave the `max`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but you could just code

```
Greatest(expense_transactions, lag(expense_transactions,1) over *blah blah*, lag(expense_transactions,2) over *same window*)
```

If your SQL flavor does not include greatest function, use more verbose Case syntax instead.  Inelegant, because it's hard to generalize to n month intervals, but it has the advantage of being accomplished within a simple, non-recursive Select statement.

Comment: The original code wasn't recursive either, and SQL Server doesn't have `GREATEST`, this also doesn't take into account not yet having 3 rows